# blue zone ftp: change protocol from SSLv3 to TLS

Tags: ftp, ssl-certificate, command-line-interface, tls

If one is changing the ftp protocol from SSLv3 to TLS, are there changes to the command line for individual ftp transfers? Or is it done using certificates only, and if so, are there any known configuration changes that must be done?
Are there any blue-zone specific changes?

Comment: Can't speak to the blue-zone stuff but there should be no need to change anything for clients, assuming they are capable of supporting TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't speak to the blue-zone stuff but there should be no need to change anything for clients, assuming they are capable of supporting TLS.

Comment: This is correct; one doesn't need to change command-line parameters and the like.  NOTE:  How logins/passwords are handled (e.g. encoding) and certificates may be affected, so be careful with these.